# Regex: how to extract date with format DD-MMM-YY? (PHP)

Tags: regex

How do I extract a date from a string that has the format DD-MMM-YY?

I have a string like this:

```
$content = '1008_My-Shoot_Day5_SAS_7-Feb-10_RCx';
```

First: How do I extract the date from this line?

Second: How do I remove everything starting from the underscore before the date to the end of the string? The output will then be:

```
$content = '1008_My-Shoot_Day5_SAS_7-Feb-10_RCx';
```

Comment: Is the string manually input and is the format consistent?

Comment: no the string is read from an excel sheet. the format is consisten.

Comment: In that case you can split the string by underscore and get the 4th index which should be 7-Feb-10.

Comment: Yes, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/QnSyU8). But really, did you try at least anything? An answer could come faster and without downvotes then.

Comment: I'm glad you've demonstrated it, Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: @apfz: So, will you post any code you have come up so far? If the comments worked I'd rather delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$re = "/.*(\\d\\d?)-([a-zA-Z]{3})-(\\d\\d?).*/"; 
$content = "1008_My-Shoot_Day5_SAS_7-Feb-10_RCx"; 
$subst = "$1-$2-$3";  
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $content);
echo $result;
```

output:

```
7-Feb-10
```

Comment: It might return even `0-___-1456789644`. Very unsafe.

Comment: pd: i´m not saying is the best option, your explode "_" is more accuarate, is just he ask for regex (at least for the regex tag) so regex it is.

Comment: One asks and here you are, doing the more tedious work for nothing? I cannot tell you not to work for free, but SO is not a place where others do work for you. We are here to *help*, not *do the whole work* for others.

Comment: @KiraCrafter. yes thank you! I wasnt able to get the regex for the data-format. That was causing the initial problem. Seeing the tension in this post, I will further explore the rest of my question :-).

Comment: This regex will match `0-NOT-1`. Again, I say, it is not a good regex for extracting dates from arbitrary text.

Comment: Well, still, it can be put (feb|jan|mar|....etc) or just replacing the two .* with more accuarate patterns(the best option)..but OP does´nt put to much details in the pattern of the input....